# How to add a foreign key null value in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I want to record to databse with foreign key is null. I know SpringBoot don't allow do it. I tried record with @Query insert . But it cannot. I send data from client format JSON.

Entity City.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "City")
public class City {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="ID_City")
Long idCity;

@Column(name="Name_City")
String nameCity;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "city")
private Collection<City> city;
/// getter and setter
```

Entity Person

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="ID_Person")
Long idPerson;

@Column(name="Name")
String namePerson;

@Column(name="Phone")
String phonePerson;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_city")
private City city;

/// getter and setter
```

Data send to SpringBoot

```
 {
    "namePerson": "New person",
    "phonePerson": "0999999",
    "city": {
        "idCity": "",
        "nameCity": ""
    }
}
```

**Question**

Is there any way to set value NULL for foreign key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `city` attribute entirely from your JSON.

Your JSON should look like this:

```json
{
    "namePerson": "New person",
    "phonePerson": "0999999"
}
```

That way your city field in `Person` object will be set to `null`, consequently storing `null` as a foreign key in a database.

Comment: Thank you. It work. But sometime it have data foreign key. How to resove it ? I only have one format JSON

Comment: You can freely add/remove the city attribute in your client (front-end UI?) as needed. spring-boot recognizes such situations and acts accordingly (setting the city field to null or to an object).